# Docker: understanding ENTRYPOINT and CMD instructions

Tags: docker

I'd like to ask some question about `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions available for use in a Dockerfile.

1. Providing that I'm mounting local directories as volumes in a container using `fig` or `docker-compose`. When exactly are `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions executed?

   - After the volumes were mounter or before?
2. If I pass a bash script to `ENTRYPOINT`, will this script be executed each time a container is started?
3. If there is a bash script added as `ENTRYPOINT`, will all commands executed with `docker run` or `docker exec` be passed as arguments to this script ?
4. When exactly are `CMD` instauctions executed? Once a container was started and volumes mounted ?
5. Why can there only be one `CMD` in a Dockerfile? What if I want to start a container with several processes / run severa exacutables?

Comment: 1) ENTRYPOINT and CMD are executed in the order they appear in the Dockerfile, regardless of the volumes mount 2) if you have an ENTRYPOINT launching a verb, you can pass a parameter 3) yes for `docker run` but some examples might clarify this, and `docker exec` just gets you inside the container 4) CMD executes swhen a container is launched 5) you can use several CMD in a Dockerfile, but only the last one will be used, docker is designed to run one process,

Comment: if you want to run several, you will need some tools such as supervisor https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/ or runit or s6 or daemontools see https://docs.docker.com/faq/

Comment: As CMD is easily overriden and not ENTRYPOINT (unless you `docker run --entrypoint...` usually you have ENTRYPOINT as the last by one line in your Dockerfile and CMD as the last line, being in fact the parameter, that can change

Comment: @user2915097 I'd suggest you make all your comments into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) ENTRYPOINT and CMD are executed in the order they appear in the Dockerfile, regardless of the volumes mount

2) if you have an ENTRYPOINT launching a verb, you can pass a parameter

3) yes for docker run but some examples might clarify this, and docker exec just gets you inside the container

4) CMD executes when a container is launched

5) you can use several CMD in a Dockerfile, but only the last one will be used, docker is designed to run one process,

if you want to run several, you will need some tools such as supervisor http://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord or runit or s6 or daemontools see http://docs.docker.com/faq

As CMD is easily overriden and not ENTRYPOINT (unless you `docker run --entrypoint`) usually you have ENTRYPOINT as the last by one line in your Dockerfile and CMD as the last line, being in fact the parameter, that can change

Comment: Just a point, if you want to start multiple things when a container is run (Not a good idea) you can use a script, add it to the container and then use this  as the CMD.